# How do we change the naked domain redirect on our App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-domain-api

Followed the instructions on: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373?hl=en

However, while changing it we get the following error:

```
Google Apps - Server error
```

Server error
We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later.

We don't even get what the error is here, and my DNS entries are (pointing towards google):

@   A   216.***.**.21 3600 delete

@   A   216.***.**.21 3600 delete

@   A   216.***.**.21 3600 delete

@   A   216.***.**.21 3600 delete

@   AAAA     2001:****:****:32:0:0:0:15 3600    delete

@   AAAA     2001:****:****:34:0:0:0:15 3600    delete

@   AAAA     2001:****:****:36:0:0:0:15 3600    delete

@   AAAA     2001:****:****:38:0:0:0:15 3600    delete

www CNAME   ghs-svc-https-c***.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com 3600    delete

@   MX 1     ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 3600    delete

@   MX 5     ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 3600   delete

@   MX 5     ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 3600   delete

@   MX 10    ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 3600   delete

@   MX 10   ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 3600    delete

@   TXT google-site-verification=Jejw*RQY 3600  delete

Comment: I had a similar issue. Http:// redirection works, but not https://. These guys offer a free redirection service which I have used - http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect.

Answer (score 0):

That article is for Google Sites, not App Engine. You can do it (it's a redirect from naked domain to a subdomain), however you need a Google Apps account to manage the SSL certificates:

**SSL for a Custom Domain**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl